# How do I connect a Facebook social plugin app with my local wamp server?

Tags: wordpress

During development of a local WordPress site, I have decided to connect my local site with Facebook social plugins. The Facebook app initially asked for some domain name in the "app domain" field of the plugin.

I do not have a domain name registered yet (I have tried and failed with `localhost`).  The app will not interact with my local site.

How can my local site hosted on wamp server interact with a Facebook social plugin?